# EC2 Ubuntu SSH Stops Working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I use about 15 EC2 instances to run some services. They are hosted on EC2 and run Ubuntu. Every once in a while the SSH stops working and the "Reachability Status" in the EC2 console shows that it is no longer reachable. This doesn't happen to all my servers, just periodically. If I stop and start the server on EC2 the problem gets fixed.

What logs can I look at for more information for why my SSH has stopped working? Does anyone have tips on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: This depends on your exact OS and version. Check `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/daemon.log` if it exists.

Comment: I have looked at all 3 of those logs and they have nothing that straddle the times of the SSH stopping. Additionally, I have some program logs that are abruptly cut off so perhaps the whole server is shut down. Does that help?

Comment: Are you using the same AMI for all the servers ? Once, I had the issue with a buggy AMI that would randomly lock. Upgrading to a more recent AMI fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.
I did a reboot and ssh'ed' into my instance and realised my instance was using too much cpu so it freezed. I was in a free account and also i had limited bandwidth and resources so i decided to upgrade my plan .It helps but is not a happy solution :p